# Group by function not working correctly in SQL server CTE

Tags: sql-server, group-by, cte

This is SQL Server CTE,

```
;with grp (Sdate,TransactionType,tot)
as

(select cast(CallStartTime as DATE)Date, Transaction_type as [Transaction type], 
    (count ([Transaction_type])) as [Total Count] 
    from TBL_AGENT_TRANSACTIONS 
    where cast(CallStartTime as DATE)>='2015-04-27' and cast(CallEndTime as Date)<='2015-04-27'  and Transaction_type in ('Debit_Card')
    group by CallStartTime, Transaction_type)

select grp.Sdate,grp.TransactionType,sum(grp.tot) as totalCount from grp group by TransactionType,grp.Sdate,grp.tot
```

Here I want to group totalcount based on Sdate and Transaction Type.
But it is not working correctly. I have 3 records with same Sdate, Transaction Type and I need to show totalcount as 3 as a single row. But i'm getting two rows as below.

[image]

Can any one help me to fix this minor issue?

Update:

I got the exact problem,

In my table '*TBL_AGENT_TRANSACTIONS*', data type of the column '*Transaction_type*' is varchar but I need to find the sum of that Transaction_type based on the Sdate and Transaction_type. If I put `sum(Transaction_type)` in the first select query, it's showing datatype covertion failed error so I'm finding the `count(Transaction_type)` in the first select query and getting sum of that field in the second select query. I guess my problem is in this process only.

Comment: You have forget to add "grp.TransactionType" in second select statement.

Comment: Yes. But I modified it and there is no change in the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add cast(CallStartTime as DATE) in your GROUP BY:

```
;with grp (Sdate,TransactionType,tot)
as
(select cast(CallStartTime as DATE)Date, Transaction_type as [Transaction type], 
(count ([Transaction_type])) as [Total Count] 
from TBL_AGENT_TRANSACTIONS 
where cast(CallStartTime as DATE)>='2015-04-27' 
    and cast(CallEndTime as Date)<='2015-04-27'  
    and Transaction_type in ('Debit_Card')
group by cast(CallStartTime as DATE), Transaction_type)

select grp.Sdate,grp.TransactionType,sum(grp.tot) as totalCount 
from grp 
group by TransactionType,grp.Sdate,grp.tot
```